# Apps Script - Google Sheets -- API Call -- trouble with token header syntax

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, bearer-token, urlfetch

Not sure how to syntax the header bearer token portion of this..

...

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// iTunes Music Discovery Application in Google Sheets
//
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// custom menu
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('iTunes API Call')
      .addItem('Get Artist Data','displayArtistData')
      .addToUi();
}

// function to call iTunes API
function calliTunesAPI(artist) {
  
  // Call the iTunes API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/music-videos/{" + artist + "}");


  --header 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjVWNjY3SEZaNjMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJTOTU0QVE5Q1Q3IieOwO'


 
  // Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
  
}


function displayArtistData() {
  
  // pick up the search term from the Google Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var artist = sheet.getRange(11,3).getValue();
  
  var tracks = calliTunesAPI(artist);
  
  var results = tracks["results"];
  
  var output = []
  
  results.forEach(function(elem,i) {
    var image = '=image("' + elem["artworkUrl60"] + '",4,60,60)';
    var hyperlink = '=hyperlink("' + elem["previewUrl"] + '","Listen to preview")';
    output.push([elem["artistName"],elem["collectionName"],elem["trackName"],image,hyperlink]);
    sheet.setRowHeight(i+15,65);
  });
  
  // sort by album
  var sortedOutput = output.sort( function(a,b) {
    
    var albumA = (a[1]) ? a[1] : 'Not known';  // in case album name undefined 
    var albumB = (b[1]) ? b[1] : 'Not known';  // in case album name undefined
    
    if (albumA < albumB) { return -1; } else if (albumA > albumB) {
      return 1;
    }
    // names are equal
    return 0;
  });
  
  // adds an index number to the array
  sortedOutput.forEach(function(elem,i) {
    elem.unshift(i + 1);
  });
  
  var len = sortedOutput.length;
  
  // clear any previous content
  sheet.getRange(15,1,500,6).clearContent();
  
  // paste in the values
  sheet.getRange(15,1,len,6).setValues(sortedOutput);
  
  // formatting
  sheet.getRange(15,1,500,6).setVerticalAlignment("middle");
  sheet.getRange(15,5,500,1).setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  sheet.getRange(15,2,len,3).setWrap(true);
  
}
```

...

This part of the code isn't working:

--header 'Content-Type:application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjVWNjY3SEZaNjMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJTOTU0QVE5Q1Q3IieOwO

Not sure how to syntax this correctly.  I'm sure this is 101, but not sure the answer.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Also replace your code by a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

With this as example you should be able to update your code. Good luck!

```
var url = "https://www.example.com"
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer ijfewfkjsfkjh4543",
  "Content-Type": "Application/json"
};

var options = {
  "method" : "get",
  "headers" : headers 
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

**EDIT:** This should do it but the API is down i see. You can delete the var artist. But i needed a number ;)

```
function calliTunesAPI(artist) { 
  var artist = 178834;
  var url = "api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/music-videos"+artist; 
  var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjVWNjY3SEZaNjMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJTOTU0QVE5Q1Q3IieOwO", 
                  "Content-Type": "Application/json" 
                }; 
  var options = { 
    "method": "get", 
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  }; 
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText(); 
  var json = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(json);
  
}
```

Comment: I tried:
---

function calliTunesAPI(artist) {
    
  var url = "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/music-videos/{" + artist + "}";
  var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjVWNjY3SEZaNjMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJTOTU0QVE5Q1Q3IieOwO",
  "Content-Type": "Application/json"
};

var options = {
  "method" : "get",
  "headers" : headers 
};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
   
}

---
Error on: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

Comment: Sorry, that paste is a nightmare.  Not sure how to format that to appear better.  Happy to DM on the side as well.

Comment: You hade some thinks not right, see my edit. The api is down for the moment

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the `UrlFetchApp` documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).

What `UrlFetchApp` does is to fetch resources and communicate with other hosts over the internet. Since you want to retrieve some data, you will essentially have to include the `bearer` and the `headers` along when making the request.

With all these taking into account, you can rewrite your function to this:

```
function calliTunesAPI(artist) {
   var url = "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/music-videos/{" + artist + "}";
   var params = {
      "headers": {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IjVWNjY3SEZaNjMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJTOTU0QVE5Q1Q3IieOwO"
      }
      "method": "GET"
   }
   var response = UrlFetchApp(url, params);
   var json = response.getContentText();
   return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

#### Reference

- [UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).